# How do I replace all instances of a string within a repeating bounds?

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have a string like this

```
<other...Stuff> BoundsTag <relevant...Stuff> EndsBoundsTag <other...Stuff> BoundsTag <relevant...Stuff> EndsBoundsTag <other...Stuff>
```

I want to do a search and replace on my string, but only change it if its within BoundsTag/EndsBoundsTag.  The string I'm trying to match exists many times in both `<relevant...Stuff>` and `<other...Stuff>`.  Also, there are an arbitrary number of BoundsTag/EndsBoundsTag pairs.

Is this possible with perl regexes?

Here is an example of a specific string where i'm trying to replace `MyMatch`

```
BoundsTag asdfasdfa MyMatch asdfasdfasdf MyMatch sdfasd EndsBoundsTag asdfasdfasdfsad **MyMatch** asd *MyMatch** asf2ef23fasdfasdf BoundsTag fghjfghj MyMatch fghjfghjgh MyMatch fghjfghj EndsBoundsTag
```

Here I would want to replace all the instance of MyMatch except for the ones between `**`.  And I don't mean specifically the characters `**`, those are just there to point it out.  Also, the spacing is just there for legibility.

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: Can those pairs be nested?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Good question, in my case no they cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that those tags always occur in pairs and are unnested, it's simple:

```
/Stuff(?=(?:(?!BoundsTag).)*EndsBoundsTag)/s
```

will match `Stuff` only if `EndsBoundsTag` can be matched after it, with no `BoundsTag` in-between.

Test it live on regex101.com.

**Explanation:**

```
Stuff           # Match Stuff
(?=             # only if the following matches afterwards:
 (?:            # 1. A group that matches...
  (?!BoundsTag) # ...unless it's the start of "BoundsTag"...
  .             # any character,
 )*             # repeated as needed.
 EndsBoundsTag  # 2. EndsBoundsTag must also be present 
)               # End of lookahead - if that succeeds, we're between tags.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work?  I've modified the other posts example to see what i mean

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work", and how did you try it? `$subject =~ s/MyMatch(?=(?:(?!BoundsTag).)*EndsBoundsTag)//sg;` should remove all `MyMatch`es from `$subject`.

Comment: Earlier when i tried it just didn't match anything.  Now when I tried your example from your comment it did match. I suspect i made a dumb mistake earlier, so thats on me.  My apologies.  Now, it is matching within the first bounds, but not the second https://regex101.com/r/nH5uR7/4

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. In Perl, you can use this regex:

```
\*{2}(?![^*]?\*{2})([^*]+?)\*{2}
```

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/bZ8dI0/2).

Comment: That only works once per tag. For `BoundsTag Stuff Stuff EndsBoundsTag`, only the first `Stuff` will match.

Comment: All of the above is not pertinent to the current OP example input and requirements (nothing is said about possible repetitions inside the tags).

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas: I updated my answer meeting your updated requirements.